# Catch a exception and show the user a warning about the failed operation

Tags: java, exception

I have a DAO method which catches exceptions in order to perform a rollback of the transaction.

```
public void edit(Employees em) {
    Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    try {
        s.beginTransaction();
        s.update(em);
        s.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        s.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

In the frontend, I'm invoking it as below.

```
public String save() {
     Employee_dao dao = new Employee_dao();
     dao.edit(emp);
     return "index";
}
```

However, I would like to catch the exception in the frontend, so I can display a message to the enduser. How can I achieve this while still performing the rollback?

Comment: _"When an insert like this fails, it takes the user back to the main menu (index.html)."_ This only happens when you tell it to do this (somewhere). The solution is to 'just' catch the error and add a faces message and show that in the client... And normally an [mcve]  and version info sould **always** be posted with a question.

Comment: The original question was overly long winded. I have rephrased it to focus on the concrete problem, which is after all not JSF/Hibernate/PostgreSQL related at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply rethrow the exception, or even wrap it in an exception that contains more information if you need it at the frontend:

```
public void edit(Employees em) throws Exception {
   // ...
   try {
      s.beginTransaction();
      // ...
   } catch (Exception e) {
      s.getTransaction().rollback();
      throw e; 
      // or throw new MyException("edit failed", e); 
      // or throw new RuntimeException(...);
   }
}

public String save() {
    Employee_dao dao = new Employee_dao();
    try {
        dao.edit(emp);
        return "index";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: With throw new MyException("edit failed", e);  I think I will only get the message "edit failed" on the IDE console. I need to show that message to the user with an alert box or something similar. The easiest solution possible to do so will be fine to me. Graphics are not imporant, I just need to show the message to the user